# Get timestamp from base64Binary in PHP

Tags: php, soap, base64, unpack

A webservice returns a timestamp field in base64Binary format. It looks like this in SOAP response:

```
<a:TimeStamp>AAAAAAMpI9Q=</a:TimeStamp>
```

PHP __soapCall, however, b64_decode()s that and I get a binary string looking like ')#▒'. How do I get actual timestamp out of this? I tried to unpack('L') it but it gives me Array([1] => 0) as a result. Is there really zero i.e. 1970-01-01 or have I missed something?

Answer (score 2):

This test program:

```
$b = "AAAAAAMpI9Q=";
$ts = base64_decode($b);
print_r(array_map("ord", str_split($ts)));
```

outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 3
    [5] => 41
    [6] => 35
    [7] => 212
)
```

showing that the base64-encoded string gives you an 8-character string when unpacked. So presumably it represents a 64-bit integer, which might be signed or unsigned, and no, it isn't zero.

Given the values above it looks like the value is 53027796 - is that what you're expecting?